# Chebychev's Inequality Question

Tags: statistics

Not sure if I'm understanding the question wrong, but the prof's notes gave a different answer.

> The number of equipment breakdowns in a manufacturing plant averages 5 per week with a standard deviation of 0.8 per week.
>
> Find an interval that includes **at least 90%** of the weekly figures for the number of breakdowns.

**My Answer:**

[image]

**Prof's Answer:**

[image]

I think he did it for at most 90%. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you write that $$P(|X-E(X)|\geq kSD(X))\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$
implies $$P(|X-E(X)|< kSD(X))> \frac{1}{k^2}$$

It would rather be $$P(|X-E(X)|< kSD(X))\geq 1- \frac{1}{k^2}$$

---

Edit: how to get from $1$ to $3$. Call $A$ the event $\{|X-E(X)|\geq kSD(X)\}$.

Then $P(A)+P(A^c)=1$ implies that if $P(A)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ then $P(A^c)\geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$. It turns out that $A^c=\{|X-E(X)|< kSD(X)\}$.

Comment: I see, could you give a derivation from the 1st equation to the 3rd one in your answer so I know why that's the case?  Thanks!

Comment: @A_for_Abacus I edited my post.

Comment: if $P(A)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$,

then 
$$1-P(A^c)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

$$-P(A^c)\le \frac{1}{k^2}-1$$

$$P(A^c)\ge 1- \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake:
$$\Pr[\lvert X - \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert \geq k\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}] \leq \frac{1}{k^2}\tag{1}$$
is **not** equivalent to
$$\Pr[\lvert X - \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert < k\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}] > \frac{1}{k^2}\,.$$
It is equivalent to
$$\Pr[\lvert X - \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert < k\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}] \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}\tag{2}$$
This explains the difference in your answers: you used $9/10$ instead of $1-9/10=1/10$.